# Build an array of objects from another array of object by selecting just a part of its properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Having the following input array:

```
const initialArray = [{name: 'john', age: 12, height: 178, likes: 'music'},
                      {name: 'mike', age: 22, height: 181, likes: 'sport'},
                      {name: 'anna', age: 18, height: 175, likes: 'sleep'},
                      {name: 'paul', age: 24, height: 170, likes: 'drink'}
                     ];
```

I want to build a new array of objects that contains only some properties, for example, just `name` and `height`. The result would be:

```
result = [{name: 'john', height: 178},
          {name: 'mike', height: 181},
          {name: 'anna', height: 175},
          {name: 'paul', height: 170}
         ];
```

Tried with `map` but probably something is wrong:

```
  const result = initialArray.map((a) => {
    a.name, a.height
  });
```

Comment: try this `initialArray.map((a) => ({name: a.name, height: a.height}));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should return the object like below.

```
const result = initialArray.map((a) => {
  return {name:a.name, height:a.height}
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You should either use `return` keyword inside `{}` or warp the code with `()` (parenthesis).

You can try using [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which allow you to specify the property names you want in the resulting objects:

```js
const initialArray = [
  {name: 'john', age: 12, height: 178, likes: 'music'},
  {name: 'mike', age: 22, height: 181, likes: 'sport'},
  {name: 'anna', age: 18, height: 175, likes: 'sleep'},
  {name: 'paul', age: 24, height: 170, likes: 'drink'}
];
const result = initialArray.map(({name, height}) => ({name,height}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

**1) Using map**

```js
const initialArray = [
  { name: "john", age: 12, height: 178, likes: "music" },
  { name: "mike", age: 22, height: 181, likes: "sport" },
  { name: "anna", age: 18, height: 175, likes: "sleep" },
  { name: "paul", age: 24, height: 170, likes: "drink" },
];

const result = initialArray.map(({ name, height }) => ({ name, height }));
console.log(result);
```

**2) Using reduce**

```js
const initialArray = [
  { name: "john", age: 12, height: 178, likes: "music" },
  { name: "mike", age: 22, height: 181, likes: "sport" },
  { name: "anna", age: 18, height: 175, likes: "sleep" },
  { name: "paul", age: 24, height: 170, likes: "drink" },
];

const result = initialArray.reduce((acc, { name, height }) => {
  acc.push({ name, height });
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

**3) Using for..of loop**

```js
const initialArray = [
  { name: "john", age: 12, height: 178, likes: "music" },
  { name: "mike", age: 22, height: 181, likes: "sport" },
  { name: "anna", age: 18, height: 175, likes: "sleep" },
  { name: "paul", age: 24, height: 170, likes: "drink" },
];

const result = [];
for (let { name, height } of initialArray) {
  result.push({ name, height });
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be with lodash's pick (if you need to dynamically resolve the name of the properties) or [ramda's pick](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick) methods are doing exactly this

```
const result = initialArray.map(R.pick(['name', 'height']));
```